# Reassign variables using ES6 destructuring assignment syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Suppose I have two objects containing the same keys but different values and I use a destructuring assignment on the first one:

```
const obj1 = {a:1, b:2, c:3}
const obj2 = {a:4, b:5, c:6}
let {a, b, c} = obj1
```

If later (say depending on some condition like the values are falsey) I was to reassign `a`, `b` and `c`, I find I have to do so like:

```
a = obj2.a
b = obj2.b
c = obj2.c
```

Since both the following give a `SyntaxError`:

```
{a, b, c} = obj2
let {a, b, c} = obj2
```

Is it possible to reassign these variables using the same syntax as used initially (using a one-liner rather than reassigning each variable inividually)? If so then how can I do this?

Comment: Thanks for the link since it explains that the accepted answer. i.e. that the parentheses `( ... )` around the assignment statement are required here, since the `{...}` operators having multiple meanings in JavaScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can surround the first option with parenthesis: `({a, b, c} = obj2);`

```js
const obj1 = {a:1, b:2, c:3}
const obj2 = {a:4, b:5, c:6}
let {a, b, c} = obj1;

console.log(a);

({a, b, c} = obj2);

console.log(a);
```